# import products from XML to CSV by PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to put the first row in a CSV document from an XML file. I got the file every time with data but I don't have first row. Please just post here if you have any idea what can be wrong. Many many thanks for all.

PHP file

```
    <?php       
          // How to Generate CSV File from Array in PHP Script   
          $url = 'https://samplewebsitegoesherewithdata.xml';
          $xml = file_get_contents($url);
          $xmls= simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

          foreach($xmls->children() as $product) {
              $productr = array(
                    "produkt"  => array(
                      "name"  => $product->CODE,  
                      "man" => $product->MANUFACTURER
                    ),
              );   

              $filename = 'export.csv';       
              header("Content-type: text/csv");       
              header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");       
              $output = fopen("php://output", "w");       
              $header = array_keys($productr[0]);       
              fputcsv($output, $header);       
              foreach($productr as $row)       
              {  
                  fputcsv($output, $row);  
              }       
              fclose($output);   
          }
```

The XML file

```
<PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCT>
        <CODE>3006.01.32.9000</CODE>
        <EAN>40034742</EAN>
        <MANUFACTURER>SAMPLE</MANUFACTURER>
        <NAME>NAME OF PRODUCT</NAME>
        <URL>
            https://sampleweb.cz/
        </URL>
        <IMGURL>https://sampleweb.cz/tmp_o/11928/img0.jpg</IMGURL>
        <IMGURL_WATERMARK>https://sampleweb.cz/tmp/11928/img0.jpg
        </IMGURL_WATERMARK>
        <ACTUAL_PRICE>2847.15</ACTUAL_PRICE>
        <ACTUAL_PRICE_VAT>3445</ACTUAL_PRICE_VAT>
        <PRICE>2847.15</PRICE>
        <PRICE_VAT>3445</PRICE_VAT>
        <CATEGORY>Stojací lampy</CATEGORY>
        <ALL_CATEGORIES />
        <CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION />
        <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
        <CONTENT>http://sampleweb.cz.cz/</CONTENT>
        <ATTRIBUTES>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Stínítko</NAME>
                <VALUE>Ø130</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Životnost</NAME>
                <VALUE>20000h</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Index podání barev</NAME>
                <VALUE>Ra 80</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Vypínač</NAME>
                <VALUE>ne</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Záruční doba</NAME>
                <VALUE>5 let</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Hmotnost g</NAME>
                <VALUE>4,676kg</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Třída ochrany</NAME>
                <VALUE>II</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Termín dodání</NAME>
                <VALUE>1-2 týdny</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Kolekce</NAME>
                <VALUE>TWIN</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Patice</NAME>
                <VALUE>LED</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Ochrana IP</NAME>
                <VALUE>IP20</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Max. příkon světelného zdroje</NAME>
                <VALUE>4,6W</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Barva</NAME>
                <VALUE>matná mosaz</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Světelný tok</NAME>
                <VALUE>400lm</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Počet světelných zdrojů</NAME>
                <VALUE>1</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Výška v mm</NAME>
                <VALUE>1570</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Včetně světelného zdroje</NAME>
                <VALUE>ano</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Napájecí napětí</NAME>
                <VALUE>230V</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Energetická účinnost</NAME>
                <VALUE>A+</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Teplota barvy světla</NAME>
                <VALUE>3000K</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Výkon</NAME>
                <VALUE>4,6W</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Hloubka v mm</NAME>
                <VALUE>470</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Výrobce</NAME>
                <VALUE>WOFI</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Barva hlavní</NAME>
                <VALUE>matná mosaz</VALUE>
                <PRICE>0</PRICE>
                <PRICE_VAT>0</PRICE_VAT>
                <AVAILABILITY>0</AVAILABILITY>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
        </ATTRIBUTES>
        <ADDITIONAL_IMAGES>
            <IMAGE>
                <IMGURL>https://sampleweb.cz.cz/tmp_o/11928/img1.jpg</IMGURL>
                <IMGURL_WATERMARK>https://sampleweb.cz/tmp/11928/img1.jpg
                </IMGURL_WATERMARK>
            </IMAGE>
        </ADDITIONAL_IMAGES>
    </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

Comment: There are several problems - but if you fix your indentation you'll see the obvious one. You're doing the code at the bottom for every product you're reading from the xml.

Comment: Could you please not use CAPS letters?

Comment: Once you've fixed that .. $productr[] = ['name' => $product->CODE, 'man' => $product->MANUFACTURER] would make more sense in your xml reading loop as then you've got an array of products rather than just one product that's being overridden constantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code - your `$productr` array is created as a multidimensional array which is pointless and the output is in the loop - although there is only 1 child element of `<products>` so it will only be done once anyway.

To extract one of the `<ATTRIBUTE>` elements based of the `<NAME>` value, this code also uses XPath to first find the element within the `<PRODUCT>` and return the `<VALUE>`.  This is done with `'//ATTRIBUTE[NAME="Životnost"]/VALUE'` and can easily be changed with the corresponding one that you want.  At `xpath()` returns a list of matching nodes, use `[0]` to extract the first element.

This code sets up the output at the start and writes the headers only for the first time...

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
$output = fopen("php://output", "w");
$headerOutput = true;
foreach($xmls->PRODUCT as $product) {
    $attr = $product->xpath('//ATTRIBUTE[NAME="Životnost"]/VALUE')[0];

    $productr = array("name"  => $product->CODE,
        "man" => $product->MANUFACTURER,
        "value" => $attr
     );

    if ( $headerOutput )    {
        $header = array_keys($productr);
        fputcsv($output, $header);
        $headerOutput = false;
    }
    fputcsv($output, $productr);
}  
fclose($output);
```

Comment: Many thanks for you thats working perfectly. You saved my life. Also I have one another question. Its possible to make csv file separated by ; not by ,

Comment: If you look at [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) you can specify the delimiter then.

Comment: Sure got it,

Could you help me with one another thing ? In the XML are many ATRIBUTES inside ATRIBUTE, I need to search for one of them forexample "Životnost" and put inside CSV value of this ATRIBUTE. Every item inside XML has same name of ATRIBUTES but in different order. So thats why I need to loop all elements of  ATRIBUTES and find "Životnost" then get his VALUE. I am not sure if its clear what I need but if not I will try to explain it in another way. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated it - it's the line `$attr = $product->xpath('//ATT...`.